# How can I only search java class in main source folder (exclude test folder) in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to find the reference of one class in eclipse, but I only want to find its usage in main source code rather than in test. So I want to exclude the reference in test code, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the folder you want to search in (e.g. src/main/java)
2. In the Search menu, click Java
3. Fill in the properties like so:

[image: parameters to fill in]

Make sure to select Limit To "References" and Scope "Selected resources".